# Parsing IF statements with JDT ASTParser

Tags: java, parsing

I'm using the Eclipse JDT ASTParser in order to parse some Java code. Everything works almost fine but I have the following issue: I have a `StatementVisitor` class that I use to parse `IF` statements. This is the relevant code:

```
public class StatementVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

   @Override
   public boolean visit(IfStatement node) {
      //Do some stuff...
      //...
      return true;
   }

}
```

In the above `visit()` method (omitted part), I parse recursively the statements included in the `IF` (including other IFs), but I only want to parse first-level `IF`.
For example, let's assume we have the following code:

```
if(a==b)
{
    if(c==d)
    {
         if(e==f)
         {
             //Some code
         }
    }
}
```

When I parse the first `IF (a==b)` I only want to parse the "first" level `IF (i.e. c==d)` and not the other `IF (e==f)`.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To stop visiting the child notes, return false from your visit method. This is a common convention in the Visitor pattern.
So in your example, to visit (a==b) and (c==d) and stop after that, the easiest way would be to have a depth counter and return false when the depth you want to reach. You also need an endVisit method to make sure the depth variable is decreased when the parser steps out of the if block.

```
public class StatementVisitor extends ASTVisitor {
   private int depth = 0;
   private static final int MAX_IF_DEPTH = 2;

   @Override
   public boolean visit(IfStatement node) {
      depth++;
      //Do some stuff...
      return depth < MAX_IF_DEPTH; //stop visiting children when max depth is reached
   }

   @Override
   public void endVisit(IfStatement node) {
      depth--;
   }

}
```